# Can I define my own functions with system function names (within a class)?

Tags: php

PHP has no problem with this code:

```
    interface IDateTimeProvider
    {
        public function date($format);
        public function time();
    }

    class DateTimeProvider implements IDateTimeProvider
    {
        public function date($format)
        {
            return date($format);
        }
        public function time()
        {
            return time();
        }
    }
```

The date() and time() functions are being defined in that class... so as long as I keep it within a class, I can name my functions with pre-existing PHP functions like date(), time() or ob_start()?

Comment: You can also use [namespaces](http://php.net/namespaces).

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking here. You already know you can "shadow" functions in a class.

Comment: Sorry, yes the question is vague. What I do mean to ask is: "hey I noticed this it is somewhat surprising, so what's the story behind this?" and I already got answers that tell me this :)

Comment: Yes, but it might confuse you later as you revise or update your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it within classes because their real name, in memory will be like `IDateTimeProvider::date`. This is called *wrapping*.

If you want to get them out of a class, you have to use namespaces like that :

```
namespace MyNamespace;
function time(){
    return \time();
 }
```

and in another file you will use it with `\MyNamespace\time();`

For the given functions, it is quite useless and I will remember you that DateTime exists in PHP and is far more powerful than timestamp and his ecosystem.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is not any problem to have functions with the name `date`, `time`, etc. in classes, because they don't conflict with those pre-defined functions with the same name.

Even more you can have classes with the same name in different [namespaces](http://php.net/namespaces) (like namespaces in C# or packages in Java and so on).

Also you can use namespace to define function with that name. For example:

```
namespace myNamespace;


function time() //function defined in 'myNamespace'
{
    return \time(); // native function time();
}
```

**Note:** while using namespaces to access functions and classes defined in "default" namespace you need to add `\` in front of those functions and classes (e.g. `\stdClass`, `\time()`, `\strpos()`, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

**YES**, you can!

Have you tried to run your code ?

[here](http://codepad.org/H2QJSFsz)'s an codepad example of your code and it's working fine